# Is there a way in javascript for me to check if an element id matches a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I coded the following:

```
var btnID = $link.attr('id');
var cityNumber = btnID.substring(4);
$('#cityLegend-1').html('City ' + cityNumber);
```

However I need this to do the last two lines only if the btnID starts with "btn-". Is there a way I could check this happens and then if the id is something like "btn-1" or "btn-999" then do the last two lines?

Comment: I think you're approaching this all wrong.  With jQuery, it should not be that verbose... you can just select an `id` that contains a string... see answer by Adil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**`.eq(-index)`**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), passing index counting backwards from the last element in the set.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hbn8t/1/)**

```
$('[id^=cityLegend-]').eq(-1) for last
$('[id^=cityLegend-]').eq(-2) for second last
```

Edit, you can use split instead of substring to get the number after hyphen.

```
var btnID = $link.attr('id');
var cityNumber = btnID.spilt('-')[1];
```

Comment: Thanks but I just want to do this for the one id that is represented by btnID. My problem is with the substr :-(

Comment: If you need the number in the id then you can use split.

Comment: @Adil You have a typo - `splt('-')` should be `split('-')`. It's too small of a change to make an edit.

Answer (score 3):

```
/** .substring() does a length check internally **/
if (btnId.substring(0,3) == "btn") { 
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: But what will happen if the id is just two characters like "XX" ?  This is one of my problems. I get an error because of the substr

Comment: You don't need to test the length first: `.substring()` doesn't give an error if you try to extract past the end, it just extracts up to the end. That is, `"XX".substring(0,4)` returns `"XX"` - which of course is not equal to `"btn-"`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Wow, you are completely correct. I have always done a length check beforehand, I never even considered that it wouldn't error out.

Answer (score 1):

So many options. This too will work :

```
var btnID = $(link).attr('id');
if(btnID.substr(0,4) == 'btn-'){
    var cityNumber = btnID.substring(4);
    $('#cityLegend-1').text('City ' + cityNumber);
}else{
    $('#cityLegend-1').text('City ' + btnID);
}
```

Comment: But what will happen if the id is just two characters like "XX" ?  This is one of my problems. I get an error because of the substr

Comment: if the id doesn't match `btn-` of course it will returned as it is. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Anne - what is the error you get? The `.substr()` method doesn't give an error if the string is shorter, e.g., `"XX".substr(0, 4)` returns `"XX"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just a the [.match()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) method and with a regex that checks if the starting 'id' starts with `btn`.

```
if (btnID.match(/^btn/g)) {
     //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how flexible your code is, but I usually approach similar set-ups a little differently.  I would do the following (which may or may not be possible for you):

- Instead of searching for an element that starts with a certain string in the `id`, why not use a specific `class` for all the buttons you might be interested in.  That way, you can use a jQuery selector like `$('.mySpecialBtn')`
- Instead of attaching an integer at the end of an `id` and then parsing it out, why not just use a `data` attribute to contain the id, i.e. `data-my-button-id="1"`?

So to put both parts together, you could have something like this:

HTML:

```
<button class="mySpecialBtn" data-my-button-id="1">Button 1</button>
<button class="mySpecialBtn" data-my-button-id="2">Button 2</button>
<button class="mySpecialBtn" data-my-button-id="3">Button 3</button>
```

JS:

```
$('mySpecialBtn').each(function() {
    var btnId = $(this).data("my-button-id"));
    // do something with btnId
});
```